# Is it TRUE that L^R = L, if and only if L is the language of palindromes?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, dfa, nfa, automata-theory

S1: LR = L, if and only if L is the language of palindromes. where LR is obtained by reversing all the strings of L.

Is S1 TRUE?

Comment: Is this a question about programming?  If so, please edit your post to clarify.

Comment: This is about Automata theory. Which is the tag I added. Didn't add any programming tags. @Tau

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample:

```
X := { all words w over {a,b}* such that |w| = 2k for some positive integer k and w = reverse(w) }
```

`Reverse(X) = X`, but `X` is not the language of all palindromes, as `"a"` is palindrome and is not a member of `X`.

Another counterexample:

```
Y := { "abc", "cba" }
```

`Reverse(Y) = Y`, but no word in `Y` is a palindrome.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking the same but one of the questions in my textbook(without explanation but only answer) does not agree. Just needed to know I'm not missing out on something.